# figure figcaption position html 5

Tags: image, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/hashie5/5p7Jk/

when you hover the image, a caption will slide up
but as you can see there is a whitespace
the caption should be positioned a few px more to the top to align with the picture

how can I do this without adding height to the figure tag, because the height of the images are going to be different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `figure img {display:block;}` to your CSS.